# Fire event listener on element not rendered in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have added an external script to my `index.html` that renders a widget inside my react component (it will render the widget where ever I wanted to. It's not a reacting component.). I'm trying to render the widget inside the id `renderDivHere`.

```
handleClick() {
  console.log("clicked on widget button")
}

render () {
  <div>
    ......
    ......
    <div id="renderDivHere" />  // the external scripts will render the widget here
    ......
  </div>
}
```

The widget contains some graphs, data and a **button with id="wl-nav-button"**. I want to **listen the click events in `#wl-nav-button` and call `this.handleClick()` function**.

I tried `jquery.click()` and `document.getElementById(wl-nav-button).addEventListener("click", function(){this.handleClick()});`. But both are returning errors.

Help me out on this issue.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Did you look up the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)?

Comment: Webpack bundling returns error. `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ( (74:10)` on document.get...

Comment: @FelixHäberle checked that link. But I can't give an `onClick` in the element as it's creating dynamically by the widget script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener("click", this.navButtonListener);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener("click", this.navButtonListener);
}

navButtonListener = (e) => {
  if(e.target.id == "wl-nav-button"){
    this.handleClick();
  }
}
```

What this does is it adds an event listener to the entire document, which is fired anytime you click. Then, a check is done to see what the clicked items `id` attribute is set to. If the `id` is your button, it fires the `handleClick()` function.

This also removes the event listener from your component before un-mounting it.

---

#### Demo

Here is a simple demo that just demonstrates how to add an event handler in React to something that was not rendered with React.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.navButtonListener);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.navButtonListener);
  }

  navButtonListener = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id == "wl-nav-button") {
      this.handleClick();
    }
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    console.log("click!!");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>A button from a simulated external non-react library will be inserted asynchronically below:</p>
        <div id="my-container"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("myApp"));

//simulate a non-react library asynchronically inserting into the DOM:
setTimeout(function() {
  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var text = document.createTextNode("Click me!");
  button.appendChild(text);
  button.setAttribute("id", "wl-nav-button");
  document.getElementById("my-container").appendChild(button);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp"></div>
```

Comment: working perfectly here. But returning some errors in my code. `Uncaught TypeError: this.handleClick is not a function`. checking the issue. Will update in some time

Comment: My bad. Made `navButtonListener` into an arrow function. Now working like charm. Thanks :)